# Angular 2: Adding a 3rd party library via Angular CLI (beta.14 webpack)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am confused while trying to import and use 3rd party libraries via Angular CLI in an Angular 2 project. The current [angular-cli README](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/e7b04ec5474c45ec4f6bce7b0797244ff7adc952/README.md#3rd-party-library-installation) on adding 3rd party libs is sparse. It mentions how to add a 3rd party library, but does not provide any examples of how to use the library, once imported. I have a couple of related questions:

- Does the library exist in it's own namespace when imported using
  `import 'library'`?
- What if a library has both javascript and css,
  how do we import both?

Examples on adding and using a 3rd party library which has both JS and CSS files (example: [photoswipe](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe)) inside an Angular2 app via Angular CLI, would be very helpful.

Versions:

- Angular CLI: beta.14
- Angular: 2.0.0.

Comment: when 3rd party provides uses some css and js then you have to keep the files in the same location as they would be using relative paths to include those in their components so u dont have to worry about those